# Sql string for this result?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple transformation I want to do to a document in my collection. I want to transform this:

```
{
  "dossier": {
    "firstName": "Mortimer",
    "lastName": "Snurd",
    "title": "Manager",
    "company": "MyCompany"
  },
  "events": {
    "eventA": {
       "questions": [
        {
          "id": 123,
          "answer": "hello"
        },
        {
          "id": 456,
          "answer": "world"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "id": "1d7070f0-a00b-46e8-87ee-67ba8e192639"
}
```

into this:

```
{
  "dossier": {
    "firstName": "Mortimer",
    "lastName": "Snurd",
  },
  "events": {
    "eventA": {
       "questions": [
        {
          "id": 123
        },
        {
          "id": 456
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "id": "1d7070f0-a00b-46e8-87ee-67ba8e192639"
}
```

I simply want to remove "title" and "company" from dossier, and remove "answer" from events.eventA.questions[].

I thought this should be fairly simple but I haven't been able to figure it out. So far I have come up with this query

```
SELECT {"firstName": c.dossier.firstName, "lastName": c.dossier.lastName} AS dossier, 
{
  "questions": {"id": q.id}
} as eventA

from c
join q in c.events.eventA.questions
WHERE c.id = '1d7070f0-a00b-46e8-87ee-67ba8e192639'
```

but it's giving me the wrong results;

```
[
    {
        "dossier": {
            "firstName": "Mortimer",
            "lastName": "Snurd"
        },
        "eventA": {
            "questions": {
                "id": 123
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dossier": {
            "firstName": "Mortimer",
            "lastName": "Snurd"
        },
        "eventA": {
            "questions": {
                "id": 456
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out once I discovered the ARRAY function. The final sql is

```
SELECT {"firstName": c.dossier.firstName, "lastName": c.dossier.lastName} AS dossier, 
{
  "questions": ARRAY(SELECT q.id from  q in c.events.eventA.questions)
} as eventA

from c
WHERE c.id = '1d7070f0-a00b-46e8-87ee-67ba8e192639'
```

I knew it would be simple. :)